# Поведенческий полиморфизм подтипов

Tags: java, c++, ооп

**Цитата из википедии:** *Наследование, — даже в языках программирования, которые поддерживают применение наследования как механизма, обеспечивающего полиморфизм подтипов, — не гарантирует поведенческий полиморфизм подтипов; смотри: «Принцип подстановки» Барбары Лисков.*

Что же здесь подразумевают под поведенческим полиморфизмом подтипов? Как грамотно и лаконично ответить на этот вопрос?

Я же понимаю это так: Опять же цитата из википедии: *Более простыми словами можно сказать, что поведение наследуемых классов не должно противоречить поведению, заданному базовым классом, то есть поведение наследуемых классов должно быть ожидаемым для кода, использующего переменную базового типа.*  Из этого следует, что наследование не защищает программиста, от того, что он может изменить поведение в переопределенном методе. Например метод `add()` в базовом классе добавляет объект, а его можно легко переопределить и этот метод станет удалять некий объект. **Сохранение поведения базового метода и есть поведенческий полиморфизм.**

Прав ли я?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы все верно понимаете. Поведенческий полиморфизм это когда дочерний класс не меняет поведения родительского. Например представьте ситуацию, у нас есть класс

```
class Rechtangle {
    protected int width;
    protected int height;

    public void setWidth(int w) {
        this.width = w;
    }

    public void setHeight(int h) {
        this.height = h;
    }

    public int area() {
        return width * height;
    }
}
```

И мы добавляем новый класс "Квадрат", чем он отличается от прямоугольника, тем что его стороны должны изменяться одновременно, если мы меняем высоту, то и должна меняться ширина, пример

```
class Square extends Rechtangle {
    @Override
    public void setWidth(int w) {
       this.width = w;
       this.height = w;
    }

    @Override
    public void setHeight(int h) {
       this.width = h;
       this.height = h;
    }
}
```

А теперь представьте, что какой-то программист написал следующий код

```
void mainProcedure(Rechtangle figure) {
    figure.setWidth(5);
    figure.setHeight(3);

    assert figure.area() == 15; 
}
```

Давайте теперь вызовем эту функцию с реализацией квадрата

`mainProcedure(new Square())`

Будет выброшено `AssertionError`, вот вам наглядное нарушение принципа LSP и поведенческого полиморфизма. Потому что фактически квадрат это не прямоугольник и разработчик процедуры `mainProcedure` не ожидал что он может получить квадрат маскирующийся за прямоугольником. Программист который написал процедуру прав. Он проверил контракт который должен был соблюдаться прямоугольником, но был нарушен квадратом.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77163/discussion-on-answer-by-vyacheslav-gusser---).